# Php query to GraphQl, using Guzzle, with array as param

Tags: php, graphql, guzzle

How to create parameterized query in PHP using guzzle for schema query like this:

```
getObject(number: [Int]): [ObjectDTO]
```

Direct query to graphQl work well as below:

```
query{
  getObject(
    number: [1, 2, 3]
  ){ someData }
}
```

Wanna make this query by quzzle actually just set Body for:

```
$body = [
 'query' => "query ($number: Int) { getObject( number: [$number],) { someData }}",
 'variables' => [
   'number' => [1, 2],
 ]
]
```

But it's not working and informed me about the wrong type of "number" variable.

When I use it the same way but instead of an array of numbers, I will put one int like **'number' => 1** query works.

Any advice on how to operate with this query?